# How to produce an inverse ecdf plot with counts rather than proportions using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I am working with a dataset which contains information about individual treatment episodes. In the dataframe `treatment`, each  row is a separate treatment episode containing a patient key (amongst other information). I would like to produce a plot which shows how many patients (y axis) have received **at least** a certain number of treatments (x axis).

The intended use of this is as follows: A researcher is planning a study that requires patients to be treated at least 10 times. They want to know how many patients in this dataset fulfil this criteria. They can look at the x-axis for the number 10 and then read the number of patients who have had 10 or more treatments.

This is the closest solution I have found but this produces a proportion on the y-axis rather than a count.

```
treatments %>%  
  group_by(patKey) %>%
  summarise(n_treatments = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n_treatments, y=1-..y..)) +
    stat_ecdf()
```

[image: Output plot]

**Edit**
Since I can't share the data itself, I would be grateful if someone could help using the in-built `USArrests` dataset (A state would translate to a patient and the number of assaults would translate to number of treatments).

```
USArrests %>% 
ggplot(aes(Assault, y=1-..y..)) +
       stat_ecdf()
```

[image: Plot]

From the plot you can see that 0.38 of states have >= 200 assaults but I would like the count on the y-axis instead i.e. 19 states with >=200 assaults.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately there are privacy issues with sharing this data. I have edited my initial post to show a comparable example using in-built `USArrests` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stat_bin` with `geom='step'` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
USArrests %>% 
  ggplot() +
  stat_bin(aes(Assault, y=cumsum(..count..)), geom = 'step') +
  labs(y = 'Count')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Reverse using `rev`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
USArrests %>% 
  ggplot() +
  stat_bin(aes(Assault, y=rev(cumsum(..count..))), geom = 'step') +
  labs(y = 'Count')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I don't think that works. If I sense check it as follows the counts at 100, 200, 300 should 40, 19, and 3.

`nrow (USArrests %>% filter(Assault >= 100))`

Comment: Hi @Mark, do you mean: `aes(Assault, y=rev(cumsum(..count..)) - ..count..)`?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misinterpreting but are you suggesting I use:
`USArrests %>% 
  ggplot() +
  stat_bin(aes(Assault, y=rev(cumsum(..count..)) - ..count..), geom = 'step') +
  labs(y = 'Count')`? That doesn't seem to work either. Essentially I'm trying to produce the same plot as produced by `USArrests %>% 
ggplot(aes(Assault, y=1-..y..)) +
       stat_ecdf()` but with the count rather than proportion on the y-axis